# Probability proportional to $n^2$

Tags: probability

> An unbiased die is such that the probability of $n$ appearing is
>   proportional to $n^2$. The die is rolled twice giving the numbers a
>   and b. Find the probability that $a<b$

**Attempt:**

Using, $P = kn^2$ and $\sum P_i = 1$,  I have obtained the value of $k = \dfrac 1 {91}$

Then,

If one appears in first, then any of the 5 remaining number may appear in 2nd throw.
If two appears, 4 numbers may appear after that
.
.
.
If six appears, then there are no favourable cases.

But I am facing difficulty in translating this into mathematical expression. How do I proceed from here?

Comment: How a die can be unbiased if different sides have different probabilities?

Answer (score 1):

We need to find the number of ways we can have two numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $a<b$.

If you select $1$ the probability of having it is $\dfrac{1}{91}$ and the probability of having other numbers greater than it would be $\dfrac{4}{91} + \dfrac{9}{91} +...+ \dfrac{36}{91}$. So, the probability of having $1$ as first number in our event would be $\dfrac{1}{91}(\dfrac{4}{91} + \dfrac{9}{91} +...+ \dfrac{36}{91})$.

Similarly, for $2$ it would be $\dfrac{4}{91}(\dfrac{9}{91}+...+ \dfrac{36}{91})$.

Add all of such probabilities for all the numbers from $1$ to $6$.

Answer (score 0):

By symmetry, the probability that the outcome of the first roll is less than the outcome of the second roll is equal to the probability that the outcome of the second roll is less than the outcome of the first roll.  Therefore, you can find the probability that the outcome of the first roll is less than the second roll by taking half of the probability that the two outcomes are not the same.  The probability that the two outcomes are not the same can be found by subtracting the probability that the two outcomes are the same from $1$.